# How to disable page element on certain articles in Joomla

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, joomla1.5

I want to make a 100% clean bootstrap template for Joomla 1.5 (i know i know but it runs as intranet application so it's safe - i dont want to mess with this ;) ) and wonder how to disable template element (ex. div) on certain article pages (not associated to selected category/section ID) or parent menu position. I want to hardcode it directly in template.

**I need something like this (example!)**

```
{if JArticle->Category-ID != 2 && 3}Do something{else}Do something else{/if}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to get the article id from the request. I'm not sure if in Joomla 1.5 this is the correct way (on latest Joomla releases, JRequest is deprecated), but anyway, you'll need to use the JRequest class.

`$id = JRequest::getInt('id');`

Then use this id:

```
if (($id != 2) && ($id != 3))
{
   // id is not 2 nor 3
}
else
{
  // otherwise
}
```